# PPTP connection disconnect

Tags: vpn, pptpd

My pptp connection wont stay connected, it will disconnect in less than a minute

here are some relevant log entries

```
May 31 13:32:31 localhost NetworkManager[931]: <info> Starting VPN service 'pptp'...
May 31 13:32:31 localhost NetworkManager[931]: <info> VPN service 'pptp' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp), PID 15216
May 31 13:32:31 localhost NetworkManager[931]: <info> VPN service 'pptp' appeared; activating connections
May 31 13:32:31 localhost NetworkManager[931]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: init (1)
May 31 13:32:31 localhost NetworkManager[931]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: starting (3)
May 31 13:32:31 localhost NetworkManager[931]: <info> VPN connection 'Dynalabs' (Connect) reply received.
May 31 13:32:31 localhost pppd[15221]: Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.5/nm-pptp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
May 31 13:32:31 localhost pppd[15221]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
May 31 13:32:31 localhost pptp[15224]: nm-pptp-service-15216 log[main:pptp.c:314]: The synchronous pptp option is NOT activated
May 31 13:32:31 localhost pppd[15221]: Using interface ppp0
May 31 13:32:31 localhost pppd[15221]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/5
May 31 13:32:31 localhost NetworkManager[931]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
May 31 13:32:31 localhost NetworkManager[931]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0): no ifupdown configuration found.
May 31 13:32:32 localhost pptp[15235]: nm-pptp-service-15216 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 1 'Start-Control-Connection-Request'
May 31 13:32:32 localhost pptp[15235]: nm-pptp-service-15216 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:739]: Received Start Control Connection Reply
May 31 13:32:32 localhost pptp[15235]: nm-pptp-service-15216 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:773]: Client connection established.
May 31 13:32:33 localhost pptp[15235]: nm-pptp-service-15216 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 7 'Outgoing-Call-Request'
May 31 13:32:34 localhost pptp[15235]: nm-pptp-service-15216 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:858]: Received Outgoing Call Reply.
May 31 13:32:34 localhost pptp[15235]: nm-pptp-service-15216 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:897]: Outgoing call established (call ID 0, peer's call ID 1536).
May 31 13:32:37 localhost pppd[15221]: CHAP authentication succeeded
May 31 13:32:37 localhost kernel: [54007.078553] PPP MPPE Compression module registered
May 31 13:32:40 localhost pppd[15221]: MPPE 128-bit stateless compression enabled
May 31 13:32:42 localhost pppd[15221]: local  IP address 10.100.0.52
May 31 13:32:42 localhost pppd[15221]: remote IP address 10.100.0.1
May 31 13:32:42 localhost pppd[15221]: primary   DNS address 4.2.2.1
May 31 13:32:42 localhost pppd[15221]: secondary DNS address 255.255.255.255
May 31 13:32:42 localhost NetworkManager[931]: <info> VPN connection 'Dynalabs' (IP Config Get) reply received.
May 31 13:32:42 localhost NetworkManager[931]: <info> VPN Gateway: 103.28.219.2
May 31 13:32:42 localhost NetworkManager[931]: <info> Tunnel Device: ppp0
May 31 13:32:42 localhost NetworkManager[931]: <info> Internal IP4 Address: 10.100.0.52
May 31 13:32:42 localhost NetworkManager[931]: <info> Internal IP4 Prefix: 32
May 31 13:32:42 localhost NetworkManager[931]: <info> Internal IP4 Point-to-Point Address: 10.100.0.1
May 31 13:32:42 localhost NetworkManager[931]: <info> Maximum Segment Size (MSS): 0
May 31 13:32:42 localhost NetworkManager[931]: <info> Forbid Default Route: no
May 31 13:32:42 localhost NetworkManager[931]: <info> Internal IP4 DNS: 4.2.2.1
May 31 13:32:42 localhost NetworkManager[931]: <info> Internal IP4 DNS: 255.255.255.255
May 31 13:32:42 localhost NetworkManager[931]: <info> DNS Domain: '(none)'
May 31 13:32:43 localhost dnsmasq[2127]: exiting on receipt of SIGTERM
May 31 13:32:43 localhost NetworkManager[931]: <info> DNS: starting dnsmasq...
May 31 13:32:43 localhost NetworkManager[931]: <info> (ppp0): writing resolv.conf to /sbin/resolvconf
May 31 13:32:43 localhost dnsmasq[15290]: error at line 2 of /var/run/nm-dns-dnsmasq.conf
May 31 13:32:43 localhost dnsmasq[15290]: FAILED to start up
May 31 13:32:43 localhost NetworkManager[931]: <info> VPN connection 'Dynalabs' (IP Config Get) complete.
May 31 13:32:43 localhost NetworkManager[931]: <info> Policy set 'Dynalabs' (ppp0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
May 31 13:32:43 localhost NetworkManager[931]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: started (4)
May 31 13:32:43 localhost NetworkManager[931]: <warn> dnsmasq exited with error: Configuration problem (1)
May 31 13:32:43 localhost NetworkManager[931]: <info> (ppp0): writing resolv.conf to /sbin/resolvconf
May 31 13:32:43 localhost dbus[872]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' (using servicehelper)
May 31 13:32:43 localhost dbus[872]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
May 31 13:33:00 localhost ntpdate[15370]: step time server 91.189.94.4 offset -1.110301 sec
May 31 13:33:21 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0xd6d6
May 31 13:33:21 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0x93aa
May 31 13:33:21 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0xcc83
May 31 13:33:21 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0x2031
May 31 13:33:21 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0x13d4
May 31 13:33:22 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0x5b11
May 31 13:33:22 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0x414b
May 31 13:33:22 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0x2f5f
May 31 13:33:22 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0xe9ff
May 31 13:33:23 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0x8e20
May 31 13:33:23 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0x8f0
May 31 13:33:23 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0xf166
May 31 13:33:23 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0x36e6
May 31 13:33:23 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0xdd19
May 31 13:33:23 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0xda26
May 31 13:33:24 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0xac5
May 31 13:33:24 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0x53a5
May 31 13:33:24 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0x507e
May 31 13:33:24 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0x1dc5
May 31 13:33:24 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0xf87b
May 31 13:33:24 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0x2f27
May 31 13:33:24 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0xd10c
May 31 13:33:24 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0x66ef
May 31 13:33:24 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0xa294
May 31 13:33:24 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0xb15
May 31 13:33:24 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0x52a2
May 31 13:33:24 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0xd863
May 31 13:33:24 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0x8a96
May 31 13:33:24 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0xde19
May 31 13:33:24 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0x9763
May 31 13:33:24 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0xb23
May 31 13:33:24 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0x83ca
May 31 13:33:24 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0x964e
May 31 13:33:24 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0xe8ae
May 31 13:33:24 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0xf614
May 31 13:33:25 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0x9b1
May 31 13:33:25 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0xf086
May 31 13:33:25 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0xbff4
May 31 13:33:25 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0x66c5
May 31 13:33:25 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0xe42
May 31 13:33:25 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0xf295
May 31 13:33:25 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0x86fe
May 31 13:33:26 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0x3bc1
May 31 13:33:26 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0xbaad
May 31 13:33:26 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0x88b5
May 31 13:33:26 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0xd7a
May 31 13:33:26 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0x30d5
May 31 13:33:26 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0x2d8f
May 31 13:33:26 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0x3933
May 31 13:33:26 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0x8d42
May 31 13:33:26 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0x4b4
May 31 13:33:26 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0xa205
May 31 13:33:26 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0x7cc5
May 31 13:33:26 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0x1b6a
May 31 13:33:26 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0xf004
May 31 13:33:26 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0x21b6
May 31 13:33:26 localhost pppd[15221]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0x51eb
```

Comment: in Windows 7 and Mac OSX, i can connect to the said PPTP server without problems

Comment: Have you tried switching the connection to asynchronous?  Does you ISP support encryption over the tunnel?

Comment: Mitch, where do i set that?

Comment: Have a look at this http://pptpclient.sourceforge.net/howto-diagnosis.phtml

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem when trying to connect from a router running OpenWRT to another router running RouterOS. Both OSes are based on linux, so I expected a painless integration. I found that at what it seemed random intervals of time the ppp tunnel would stop working, although not disconnect. The same errors you mentioned popped up in my debug log as well.

After some debugging I found out that the random intervals were not random but coincided with high traffic being transfered over the tunnel - when I was running backups over the PPTP tunnel.
What I did to solve my problem was disable the CCP compression by adding the following line to my `/etc/ppp/options.pptp` (The location and name of file may be different in the distro you are running):

```
noccp
```

Comment: Same issue here (`Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol`), I had no  lucky with your solution

Comment: Thanks, this helped!

Answer (score 4):

The PPTP server to which you are trying to connect might not support some compression features.

You can try to disable (all of them):

- BSD compression;
- Deflate compression;
- TCP header compression.

With some Windows PPTP servers disabling PPP Echo packets sending may help too.

You'll find these options in the configuration window of your VPN connection (VPN tab -> Advanced).

If disabling compression features does not solve your problem it might also be linked to the DNS error which we can see in your log excerpt.

Try to set the DNS manually like this:
Go to the configuration window of your VPN connection, in IPv4 parameters tab,  and change the method to "automatic addresses only (VPN)". Then type the address of the DNS server as well as the search domain. Please ask your network administrator if you do not know these.

I hope that this will help you to solve your connection problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm experiencing same issue on 13.04

this is, I think, related to this bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-pptp/+bug/290178

Check your `/var/log/syslog` for lines as **Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol**

I have solved it a couple of month ago installing some package from debian unstable

check also this:
https://forum.linode.com/viewtopic.php?p=36204/

mtu 1400
and also check out for gre protocol and 1723 port are open.

Answer (score 0):

In Kali Linux I tried enabling ONLY mschapv2 authentication, because this was on the router
I used only 128 bit encryption and I disabled the Deflate data.

I had disconnections 1 sec after the connection.

Now I've had it for hours and no problem.

Answer (score 0):

When attempting to connect to a windows VPN server from Ubuntu 14.04, I would also see PPTP diconnects and would find this error in my `/var/log/syslog`,

> "nm-pptp-service-9270 warn[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:956]: Non-zero Async
>   Control Character Maps are not supported!"

I found my answer on [this forum](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=235788). The advice was: Windows VPN's only work with mppe authentication. To use this, either set the following lines in `/etc/ppp/options.pptp`

```
refuse-pap
refuse-eap
refuse-chap
refuse-mschap
require-mppe
```

Or go to the advanced settings of the VPN in the graphical network manager and sure only MSCHAPv2 is checked. uncheck the others (pap, chap, mschap, eap) and also enable mppe.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the cause was that the mtu size of the vpn, was bigger than the path to the host, so you can use traceroute to discover the lower mtu in the path to the host.
the command is:
`traceroute <host> --mtu`

In my case the lower MTU was 1280, so I used 1200 to make the vpn in the router configuration.